# How to control what Ruby interpreter Puppet uses?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have an app that requires Ruby 2.1 and use Puppet to provision a handful of servers.

The problem is, when I install on the 2.1 version of Ruby, Puppet starts using that, and it is not supported.

I would like to somehow point Puppet to a 2.0 version of Ruby installed in `/opt`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us how your Puppet code calls the Ruby scripts.

Comment: Is this Puppet Enterprise or Community?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could add a shebang line in the .rb file that points to the other version of ruby?

Alternatively you could try to specifically add the bin/ruby location in /opt to the $PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you shouldn't let the system determine the path, but instead provide the full path to the Ruby interpreter you want to execute your script:

```
/usr/bin/ruby /some/path/to/foo.rb
```

Or:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby1.9.2 /path/to/bar.rb
```